# How to "create or update" using F object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to create LeaderboardEntry if it is not exists. It should be updated with the new value (current + new) if exists. I want to achieve this with a single query. How can I do that?

Current code looking like this: (2 queries)

```
reward_amount = 50

LeaderboardEntry.objects.get_or_create(player=player)
LeaderboardEntry.objects.filter(player=player).update(golds=F('golds') + reward_amount)
```

PS: Default value of "golds" is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have one query hit less with the `defaults` :

```py
reward_amount = 50

leader_board, created = LeaderboardEntry.objects.get_or_create(
    player=player,
    defaults={
        "golds": reward_amount,
    }
)

if not created:
    leader_board.golds += reward_amount
    leader_board.save(update_fields=["golds"])
```

Comment: I think it's the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: I liked your solution. Really interesting how you use defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the `get_or_create()` method so it return back a tuple with two values, `(object, created)` so you have to recieve them in your code as following:

```
reward_amount = 50

entry, __ = LeaderboardEntry.objects.get_or_create(player=player)
entry.golds += reward_amount
entry.save()
```

It will work better than your actual code, just will avoid make two queries.

Of course the `save()` method will hit again your database.

Comment: The code above I wrote is working. The "player" variable comes from upside of the code block. Actually your code queries 2 times too. :(

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun I updated the code, I got the clear idea of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
LeaderboardEntry.objects.update_or_create(
    player=player,
    defaults={
        'golds': F('golds') + reward_amount
    }
)
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry, `F` expressions in `update_or_create` are [not yet supported](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25195).

Comment: I get this error in case of CREATE: 
F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.